# Magento 2: How to get the price of a product?

Tags: magento2, product, price, tax, discount

I know this might be a simple question to ask, but I'm wondering what's the proper way to get the price of a product?

I know most of you might say *"use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::getPrice()"*, but that returns the price like it's set in the admin. Just the value as it is in the database. But note that to answer the question *"what's the price of the product?"* there are several factors you need to consider:

- What's the store view?
- What's the current currency?
- What's the tax?
- Are the catalog prices including or excluding tax? (configuration settings)
- Should I display / calculate taxes on the frontend? (configuration settings)
- Is there a special price? (and what's the from/to date?)
- Are there any special catalog price rules?
- Are there tier prices?
- If the customer is logged in, are there different prices?
- Are there other modules that manipulate the price in some way?

As you can see, a simple `getPrice()` won't do. So what I'm wondering, is there any Service Contract that I'm not aware of that takes all of the above in consideration and returns me the proper price?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getFinalPrice()` coming from the below product model.

It also allows a `$qty` variable in case of tier prices.

i.e.:

```
$myProduct->getFinalPrice(3);
```

Reference:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getFinalPrice($qty = null);
```

**NOTE:**
It is not defined in `ProductInterface`, so it will not be part of service contract. But it will work anyway.

**UPDATE:**:
The best Magento2 way to preserve service contracts model is to create a new custom `ProductInteface` in a **custom module** and reference `getFinalPrice` as interface method.

You will have to use the new `ProductInterface` in your project. This is the way to create a **sort of service contract inside your project**.

If **getFinalPrice** will change, **you will change only your custom model**.

Comment: I know about the `getFinalPrice()`-method, but I was just wondering if there was a service contract-way of doing this. But I guess there isn't any then.

Comment: AFAIK it does not, at least nothing in ProductInterface

Comment: Updated with suggested strategy

Comment: Interesting strategy. But perhaps an intercepter that adds a custom attribute or extension attribute might be a better approach. That way I don't have to set a new preference for an interface.

Comment: Yes, that is another interesting and clever strategy.

Comment: I just do not like to use extension_attributes for "non-custom" information. But I think the approach you suggest is even less invasive than mine and REST-API ready.

Comment: In my case I used getFinalPrice method to calculate the product price via ajax based on quantity. However, the qty argument doesn't work for me, I only get the final price for the product with quantity 1. Is this a bug or am I missing something?